# PDO - Prepare, SELECT FROM

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

The `var_dump` gets me this result:  `array(0) { }`

If I `var_dump $this->loginUsername`, it's properly filled.

What's my error?

```
    function dbCheckLogin(){

    $stmt = $this->dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM members WHERE usr = ':loginUsername'");
    $stmt->bindParam(':loginUsername', $this->loginUsername);
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
    var_dump($result);
    }
```

Comment: Remove the quotes around your placeholder.

Comment: @MikeW - Thanks, I did that. But $result still gets me an empty array.

Comment: remove the quotes around the placeholder.  Ha +1 @Mike you beat me to it.  What is in loginUsername?  Are you sure you have the correct user login >?  One thing to do is open phpmyadmin and run the exact query you want to, for example fill in the placeholder with the contents of loginUsername, then you can rule out a DB record issue and other query problems.

Comment: ^^^ *but of course!*

Comment: @Fred-ii- 
http://i.imgur.com/9kEsCf1.jpg
http://i.imgur.com/9gwmeF6.jpg
http://i.imgur.com/Ozu092k.jpg

Comment: @Darren I want to use 'prepared statements' on this form, for security. How do I achieve this?

Comment: @icor103 See my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26621899/2518525) below

Comment: Thanks, gentlemen. Up votes given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's one thing you're forgetting. You need to execute the query to be able to fetch the results.

```
$stmt->execute();
```

Refer to the docs: [`fetchAll()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php)

---

**Edit:** for clarity, this is what your function should look like:

```
function dbCheckLogin(){

    $stmt = $this->dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM members WHERE usr = :loginUsername");
    $stmt->bindParam(':loginUsername', $this->loginUsername);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
    var_dump($result);
}
```

Comment: pleasure mate! and thanks @Fred-ii- for picking up my stupidity!

Comment: You're welcome Darren.